# Weird linq2sql/let bugs?

Tags: linq-to-sql

Can someone explaing why existence of the following linq query...

```
(from e in db.Clients
                    let
                        log = (from f in db.CreditsafeLogs where f.Vat.Equals(e.VAT) orderby f.Sent descending select f).FirstOrDefault()
                    where
                        e.DeleteFlag.Equals("n") &&
                        e.Active == true &&
                        log != null &&
                        log.Approved == false
                    select e.Id)
```

compiles, but in runtime breaks the application (even though it's never called), while it's equivalent

```
Clients
   .Select (
      e => 
         new  
         {
            e = e, 
            log = CreditsafeLogs
               .Where (f => f.Vat.Equals (e.VAT))
               .OrderByDescending (f => f.Sent)
               .FirstOrDefault ()
         }
   )
   .Where (
      temp0 => 
            (((temp0.e.DeleteFlag.Equals ("n") && (temp0.e.Active == (Boolean?)True)) && 
                  (temp0.log != null)
               ) && 
               (temp0.log.Approved == False)
            )
   )
   .Select (temp0 => temp0.e.Id)
```

Works fine??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we have no way of reproducing it, can you define "breaks the application"? Can you cite the error message please? For info, I have occasionally seen the expression compiler make dubious decisions about nullability - for more see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586097/compare-nullable-types-in-linq-to-sql/586109#586109). This might be related, but impossible to say without the error message.

Comment: I'm using the flourinefx AMF gateway and the problem is that some "RPC methods" stops works (or can't be found by flourine).

Comment: Unfortunately, I still don't think that is enough detail to even begin to answer this...