# LINQ to SQL - nullable types in where clause

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have a table with a column that has null values... when I try to query for records where that column IS NULL:

THIS WORKS:

```
        var list = from mt in db.MY_TABLE
                   where mt.PARENT_KEY == null
                   select new { mt.NAME };
```

THIS DOES NOT:

```
        int? id = null;
        var list = from mt in db.MY_TABLE
                   where mt.PARENT_KEY == id
                   select new { mt.NAME };
```

Why?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the SQL generated in each case? What's the type of mt.PARENT_KEY?

Comment: In the generated code? Nullable<int>, Nullable<long>?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

after some more googling, I found the answer:

[ref #1](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/linqprojectgeneral/thread/d00f5611-4fce-4da4-8f79-802336fdfe1a)

[ref #2](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/linqprojectgeneral/thread/fad48931-3322-4e38-b9f2-80601a325351/)

```cs
int? id = null;
var list = from mt in db.MY_TABLE
           where object.Equals(mt.PARENT_KEY, id)  //use object.Equals for nullable field
           select new { mt.NAME };
```

**This LINQ renders to SQL as follows:**

```
((mt.PARENT_KEY IS NULL) AND (@id IS NULL)) 
OR ((mt.PARENT_KEY IS NOT NULL) AND (@id IS NOT NULL) AND (mt.PARENT_KEY = @id))
```

Answer (score 5):

One possibility - if `mt.PARENT_KEY` is of some other type (e.g. `long?`) then there will be conversions involved.

It would help if you could show the types involved and the query generated in each case.

EDIT: I think I have an idea...

It could be because SQL and C# have different ideas of what equality means when it comes to null. Try this:

```
where (mt.PARENT_KEY == id) || (mt.PARENT_KEY == null && id == null)
```

If this *is* the case then it's a pretty ugly corner case, but I can understand why it's done that way... if the generated SQL is just using

```
WHERE PARENT_KEY = @value
```

then that won't work when value is null - it needs:

```
WHERE (PARENT_KEY = @value) OR (PARENT_KEY IS NULL AND @value IS NULL)
```

which is what the latter LINQ query should generate.

---

Out of interest, why are you selecting with

```
select new { mt.NAME }
```

instead of just

```
select mt.NAME
```

?) Why would you want a sequence of anonymous types instead of a sequence of strings (or whatever type `NAME` is?

Comment: I have updated Nick's answer to reflect how Object.Equals renders to SQL. In your opinion, is the extra `(mt.PARENT_KEY IS NOT NULL) AND (@id IS NOT NULL)` in Line 2 superfluous? This is suggested by the your answer. (More characters of LINQ, fewer characters of SQL)

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely a matter of C# and SQL having different notions of how to compare nulls - the question has been addressed here before:

[Compare nullable types in Linq to Sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586097/compare-nullable-types-in-linq-to-sql)