# LINQ: Nullable value types in where clause

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, nullable

I'm trying to query a table with possible NULL values. According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126133/linq-to-sql-nullable-types-in-where-clause), using `object.Equals` is the way to do it:

```
DateTime? myDate = null;
var q =
    from row in db.Activities
    where object.Equals(row.FirstActivityTime, myDate)
    select row;
```

This works, but when I assign a non null value to `myDate`,

```
DateTime? myDate = DateTime.Now;
```

it all falls apart and throws the exception *"Unable to cast the type 'System.Nullable`1' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types".*

I could rewrite the where clause into

```
where row.FirstActivityTime == myDate || (row.FirstActivityTime == null && myDate == null)
```

but is there any way to make this work with `object.Equals`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using LINQ to Entities rather than LINQ to SQL, the question you're referencing doesn't apply. You can just use `row.FirstActivityTime == myDate` in your filter and EF will generate the correct SQL query, incorporating an `is null` check along with the equality check.

**EDIT**

It turns out this behavior has been changed a bit, and you need to set a flag on the context to get the old behavior back. (source: http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/178)

```
var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext).ObjectContext;
objectContext.ContextOptions.UseCSharpNullComparisonBehavior = true;
```

After doing that, the `is null` checks will be included in the generated SQL.

Comment: No. I've tried it, and the generated SQL does **not** have the required `IS NULL` check in this case.

Comment: @JohnReynolds, is row.FirstActivityTime nullable?

Comment: @JohnReynolds So in what way is the output incorrect when using this query?

Comment: @Servy: If both row.FirstActivityTime and myDate are NULL, I want the row to be included in the result set. It will not be when using this query.

Answer (score -5):

You should write this:

```
var q = from row in db.Activities 
        where (mydate.HasValue && 
            DateTime.Equals(row.FirstActivityTime, myDate.Value))
        select row;
```

Comment: -1: This where clause will not include any rows with NULL values.

Comment: hum ok i see. You should mark your FirstActivityTime as NULLABLE in your database and update your .edmx file. otherwise you will not be able to do such a query

Comment: @FranckNgako It is already nullable, based on the code shown in the question.

Comment: @Frank: I *am* able to do such a query. That's what the rewritten where clause in my original post does. The question is about ... ah well, just read it again and you will see.

Comment: @Servy you're right. Well then my last idea is to use the following syntax where `Nullable<Datetime>(row.FirstActivityTime, myDate)`