# Linq to SQL: Using int? as a parameter in a query

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

So I have a query that looks something like this:

```
var clams = from clam in Clams
            where clam.ClamTypeID == 143 &&
                  clam.ParentClamID == null
            select clam;
```

Nothing too crazy, returns the results that I need.  But when I have it in a function where I'm passing in the possible null value as a int? I start to run into an issue.  Here is what my function looks like:

```
public IQueryable<Clam> getAllClams(int clamTypeID, int? parentClamID)
{
     return from clam in Clams
            where clam.ClamTypeID == clamTypeID &&
                  clam.ParentClamID == parentClamID
            select clam;
}
```

This function returns nothing - I checked the params to make sure they were correct and sure enough, parentClamID == null and still, no results. If I change clam.ParentClamID == parentClamID to clam.ParentClamID == null it works so I'm assuming I'm using int? incorrectly...any idea's what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Here's a question for nullable types in general: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586097/compare-nullable-types-in-linq-to-sql

Comment: I love that you're querying for clams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had this problem in the past. The workaround I found to work was this:

```
public IQueryable<Clam> getAllClams(int clamTypeID, int? parentClamID)
{
     return from clam in Clams
            where clam.ClamTypeID == clamTypeID &&
                  object.Equals(clam.ParentClamID, parentClamID)
            select clam;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public IQueryable<Clam> getAllClams(int clamTypeID, int? parentClamID)
{
     return from clam in Clams
            where clam.ClamTypeID == clamTypeID &&
                  clam.ParentClamID == parentClamID.HasValue ? parentClamID.Value : null 
            select clam;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public IQueryable<Clam> getAllClams(int clamTypeID, int? parentClamID)
{
     var result = from clam in Clams where clam.ClamTypeID == clamTypeID select clam;

      if(parentClamID.HasValue) result = result.Where(c => c.ParentClamID == parentClamID);
      else result = result.Where(c => c.ParentClamID == null);

      return from clam in result select clam;
}
```