# LINQ2SQL A problem with return items based on a parameter

Tags: linq-to-sql

I occured a strange problem. I have that method

```
public static void ProcessCategories(int? myID)
{
  var tmpList = Adapter.Category.Where(x => x.IdParentCategory == myID).ToList();
}
```

when `myID == null` (the parameter), the tmpList doesn't contain any elements, but if I type

`x.IdParentCategory == null` then some items are returned. Why ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static void ProcessCategories(int? myID)
{
  var tmpList = Adapter.Category.Where(x => x.IdParentCategory == myID || (myID == null && x.IdParentCategory == null)).ToList();
}
```

Comment: I think this is because in sql you have to compare nulls like this: where column is null. but non nulls values with =

Comment: that code generates an error 'Delegate 'System.Func<AdvertisingService.BO.Category.Category,int,bool>' does not take 1 arguments'

Comment: Well.. I don't know why that is. but here is a someone with the same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586097/compare-nullable-types-in-linq-to-sql