# Nullable Parameter used in Lambda Query is being ignored

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-3, ado.net

I'm trying to pass a null value from a RenderAction to another view. But in between, at the controller, my linq lambda expression is not loading the right field, despite the null value going through correctly..

SprintManager.cshtml

```
<div id="Global_Backlog_Board" class="Board_Panel">
    @{Html.RenderAction("ListOfSingleCards", new 
        { 
            State_ID = 1
        });}
</div>
```

HomeController.cs

```
public PartialViewResult ListOfSingleCards( int? Sprint_ID,
                                            int State_ID = 1)
{
    var Cards = db.Cards.Where(x => x.State_ID == State_ID &&
                                    x.Sprint_ID == Sprint_ID && 
                                    x.Deleted != 1 && 
                                    x.Archive != 1).ToList();
    return PartialView(Cards);
}
```

So Sprint_ID is being passed over and loaded as null here, but I can't get the query to load the rows correctly.

In fact, the following works:

```
var Cards = db.Cards.Where(x => x.State_ID == State_ID &&
            x.Sprint_ID == null && 
            x.Deleted != 1 && 
            x.Archive != 1).ToList();
```

So I suppose I could check if Sprint_ID is null and depending on the result run one of the two seperate queries, but I'd like to understand why my original attempt is not working.

Thank you!

Comment: maybe it's a little off topic or it might even solve your problem... but when you make more than one condition in a lambda expression you should put them all in one bracket. f.ex `.Where(x => (x.State_ID == State_ID &&
                                        x.Sprint_ID == null && 
                                        x.Deleted != 1 && 
                                        x.Archive != 1))...`

Comment: Take a look at the following answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586097/compare-nullable-types-in-linq-to-sql/586109#586109

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I gave it a try but my problem persists. I've never put the conditions in their own parenthesis before - Is there a reason to do this? Is it just the standard?

Comment: Hey Darin - That link helped a bit. I don't know how to write those custom Expressions - so if you want to take a crack at it, I can upvote your response. Otherwise, I think I might just stick to my solution listed down below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the correct answer but based on your solution you should be able to tidy it up:

```
var cards = new List<Card>();
var query = db.Cards.Where(x => x.State_ID == State_ID &&
                                x.Deleted != 1 &&
                                x.Archive != 1);

if (Sprint_ID.HasValue) 
    query = query.Where(x => x.Sprint_ID == Sprint_ID);
else
    query = query.Where(x => x.Sprint_ID == null);

cards = query.ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

A nullable int won't return "null" in the way that you're thinking.  You have to check the HasValue property of it to determine if there is a value, and if so then use it otherwise use null:

```
public PartialViewResult ListOfSingleCards( int? Sprint_ID,
                                            int State_ID = 1)
{
    var Cards = db.Cards.Where(x => x.State_ID == State_ID &&
                                    x.Sprint_ID == Sprint_ID.HasValue ? Sprint_ID.Value : null && 
                                    x.Deleted != 1 && 
                                    x.Archive != 1).ToList();
    return PartialView(Cards);
}
```

Comment: Tried: x.Sprint_ID == (int?)(Sprint_ID.HasValue ? Sprint_ID.Value : (int?)null) && but it still doesn't return the correct values from the db. :(

Comment: What is the datatype of x.Sprint_ID?  Why are you casting the null and the return of the ternary expression to 'int?'?  That would change the comparison completely; I don't see how what I provided is different from your example of what you're using in the meantime.

Comment: Sprint_ID is an int? but your response doesn't compile in Visual Studio. I get the following: Error: Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int?' and 'bool'.

Answer (score 0):

Until something better comes a long, I'm using this:

```
var Cards = new List<Card>();

if (Sprint_ID == null)
{
    Cards = db.Cards.Where(x => x.State_ID == State_ID &&
                                x.Sprint_ID == null &&
                                x.Deleted != 1 &&
                                x.Archive != 1).ToList();
}
else
{
    Cards = db.Cards.Where(x => x.State_ID == State_ID &&
                                x.Sprint_ID == Sprint_ID &&
                                x.Deleted != 1 &&
                                x.Archive != 1).ToList();
}
```