# Problems with nullable types in a LINQ Function

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-objects, nullable

`Parent_ObjectiveID` and `identity` are `int?` datatype. In my program should return an object, but it gives an error: `Sequence contains no elements`.

```
int? identity = null;

Objective currentObjective = (from p in cd.Objective
                              where p.Parent_ObjectiveID == identity
                              select p).Single();
```

Although, if I replace identity variable to null. It works, but I don't understand.

```
currentObjective = (from p in cd.Objective
                    where p.Parent_ObjectiveID == null
                    select p).Single();
```

What's happening?

**UPDATE 1:**

I have done this:

```
if (identity == null)
{
     currentObjective = (from p in cd.Objective
                         where p.Parent_ObjectiveID == null
                         select p).Single();
}
else
{
     currentObjective = (from p in cd.Objective
                         where p.Parent_ObjectiveID == identity
                         select p).Single();
}
```

But I don't really like it.

Comment: Are you talking about Linq-To-Sql or Linq-To-Objects? I just tested this with Linq-To-Objects, and it works for me. (.NET 4.0)

Comment: Why did you tag it with `linq-to-objects` then? ;)

Comment: I thought it'll be the same problem for both

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compare nullable types in Linq to Sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586097/compare-nullable-types-in-linq-to-sql)

Answer (score 1):

LINQ does not seem to support this case in the where clause.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586097/compare-nullable-types-in-linq-to-sql) is about the same problem. Also see [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/linqprojectgeneral/thread/d00f5611-4fce-4da4-8f79-802336fdfe1a/).

You could try:

```
Objective currentObjective = (from p in cd.Objective
                                  where p.Parent_ObjectiveID == (identity ?? null)
                                  select p).Single();
```

EDIT: If this does not work, try to compare with object.Equals:

```
Objective currentObjective = (from p in cd.Objective
                                  where object.Equals(p.Parent_ObjectiveID, identity)
                                  select p).Single();
```

Comment: The first code should work, although it returns a (int?)null and to work it would be just null.

Maybe I should work with Where claussule and expressions to eliminate that super if

Answer (score 0):

I found an article at [LINQ to SQL Null check in Where Clause](http://www.brentlamborn.com/post/LINQ-to-SQL-Null-check-in-Where-Clause.aspx) that explains this problem.  It looks like you can use `object.Equals` instead:

```
from p in cd.Objective
where object.Equals(p.Parent_ObjectiveID, identity)
select p
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from p in cd.Objective
where p.Parent_ObjectiveID == identity
select p
```

will be compiled to 'select * from objective where Parent_ObjectiveID **== @identity**'. And,

```
from p in cd.Objective
where p.Parent_ObjectiveID == null
select p
```

will be compiled to 'select * from objective where Parent_ObjectiveID **is null**'.

The clause 'where Parent_ObjectiveID == null' will always return 'false' when your @identity is null.