# Linq to SQL: Where clause comparing a Nullable<DateTime> with a SQL datetime null column

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

Using C#, Linq to SQL, SQL Server, I have this:

```
MyTable has a column with a "datetime null" column.

DateTime? aDateTime;

var records = (from row in MyTable where row.StartDate == aDateTime);
```

And I noticed that the query does not do what I expected.  Specifically, if aDateTime is null, it queries `StartDate = null` rather than `StartDate IS null`, which does not find records where the column value is null.  Changing it to:

```
where aDateTime.HasValue ? (row.StartDate == aDateTime) : (row.StartDate == null)
```

works but is annoying.  Is there a simpler solution to this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586097/compare-nullable-types-in-linq-to-sql

Comment: How about DateTime.Compare() ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think `Object.Equals(row.StartDate, aDateTime)` will do the trick.

There is lots about this [on Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=linq+null). For example, [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/linqprojectgeneral/thread/d00f5611-4fce-4da4-8f79-802336fdfe1a/).

Comment: So this problem extends to all nullable base datatypes?