# Linq to SQL nullable int?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I have the following linq query (pretty simple):

```
var jobs = from j in db.jobmsts
    join jd in db.jobdtls on j.jobdtl_id equals jd.jobdtl_id
    where j.jobmst_type != 1 && j.jobmst_prntid.Equals(folder.FolderID)
    orderby j.jobmst_name
    select new
        {
            JobID = j.jobmst_id,
            JobName = j.jobmst_name,
            Description = j.jobmst_desc,
            Source = jd.Source
        };
```

folder.FolderID is a nullable int (int?) that is passed into the method as a parameter.  So, when it's null, the query returns no results.  But if I execute the same query in TSQL:

```
select * from jobmst j 
join jobdtl jd on j.jobdtl_id = jd.jobdtl_id 
where j.jobmst_type != 1 and j.jobmst_prntid is null
```

I get 6 records.  Oddly, if I substitute "folder.FolderID" with "null" (in the linq code), it does return 6 records.  So, obviously there's a difference between "null" and an object with a null value.  I just don't know what is it and how to fix this.

FYI, I had the code so that the where clause looked like this:

```
where j.jobmst_type != 1 && j.jobmst_prntid == folder.FolderID
```

But it didn't produce any results either.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does SQL Profiler show when you execute that linq?

Comment: Also - you are constructing a linq query object here, but NOT executing it (at least in the code you have shared with us).

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586097/compare-nullable-types-in-linq-to-sql

Comment: I'm not familiar with SQL Profiler.  The db object is a DataClasses1DataContext object added to my project.

Comment: The output from the db.log is "WHERE ([t0].[jobmst_type] <> @p0) AND ([t0].[jobmst_prntid] = @p1)"

Comment: p0: Input Int (Size = -1; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [1]
p1: Input Int (Size = -1; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [Null]

Answer (score 3):

As I already mentioned it in a comment: [Compare nullable types in Linq to Sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586097/compare-nullable-types-in-linq-to-sql)

The answer to that question also applies here: Linq to SQL behaves kind of strangely when querying nullable types. The solution is to check for `null` explicitly if the value of the nullable type is `null`. If you don't want to write two queries, just write different where clauses (you have to mix in some lambda syntax):

```
Expression<Func<Job,bool>> predicate;
if(folder.FolderID == null) {
    predicate = j=>j.jobmst_prntid == null && j.jobmst_type != 1;
} else {
    predicate = j=>j.jobmst_prntid == folder.FolderID && j.jobmst_type != 1;
}

//...
.Where(predicate)
select new
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to prepend `(int ?)` in the expression to work when you have null

```
j.jobmst_prntid.Equals ( folder.FolderID )
j.jobmst_prntid.Equals ( (int ? ) folder.FolderID )
```

For more reference:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882535.aspx

or you can try this

```
 where j.jobmst_type != 1 && j.jobmst_prntid.Equals(folder.FolderID== null ?   null : folder.FolderID)
```

Comment: That syntax is for a nullable value in the join statement.  My issue is a nullable value in the where clause.  I tried the syntax but it didn't work.  Thanks tho.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this for my situation:

```
List<Job> folderJobs = new List<Job>();
var tidalJobs = (dynamic) null;
if (folder.FolderID == 0)
{
    tidalJobs = from 
                    master in tidal.jobmsts
                join
                    detail in tidal.jobdtls
                on
                    master.jobdtl_id equals detail.jobdtl_id
                where 
                    master.jobmst_prntid.HasValue == false && master.jobmst_type != 1
                select new
                {
                    JobID = master.jobmst_id,
                    JobName = master.jobmst_name,
                    Description = master.jobmst_desc == null ? string.Empty : master.jobmst_desc,
                    Source = detail.jobdtl_cmd == null ? string.Empty : detail.jobdtl_cmd
                };
}
else
{
    tidalJobs = from
                    master in tidal.jobmsts
                join
                    detail in tidal.jobdtls
                on
                    master.jobdtl_id equals detail.jobdtl_id
                where 
                    master.jobmst_prntid == folder.FolderID && master.jobmst_type != 1
                select new
                {
                    JobID = master.jobmst_id,
                    JobName = master.jobmst_name,
                    Description = master.jobmst_desc == null ? string.Empty : master.jobmst_desc,
                    Source = detail.jobdtl_cmd == null ? string.Empty : detail.jobdtl_cmd
                };
}

foreach (var folderJob in tidalJobs)
{
    ...
}
```

In short, var tidalJobs = (dynamic) null and .HasValue == false is what I needed to get this working.  The only caveat is that setting a var to (dynamic) null disables intellisense b/c everything is evaluated at runtime.  So, your typing better be spot on.