# Entity Framework Core Linq query doesn't translate to correct SQL statements

Tags: mysql, sql, windows, vb.net, entity-framework-core

So I am debugging our application which uses Entity Framework Core 2.1.14. I created my entities from database first by scaffolding. Database is MySQL 5.7.29, the SQL data provider for EF Core is Oracle's MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore 8.0.19.

Example: a simple Linq query should create a proper SQL statement in the backend. However it does not. "Inactive" is a Byte?.

```
Dim associates = (From a In DatabaseContext.Associate
                  Where a.Inactive = 0
                  Select a.AssociateId).ToList()
```

This simple Linq query returns: `` SELECT `a`.`Inactive`, `a`.`AssociateID` FROM `associate` AS `a` ``. So basically it downloads all associates and does the "where" in memory and returns the values. I know according to the documentation some queries can be complicated and can't be translated, but this is a simplest of the simple queries. Is it because the Inactive column is nullable? Something is terrible not right.

FYI: EF Core is in a class library that is C#. The VB code is in another project that is VB that references the class library.

Comment: Does `Dim associates = DatabaseContext.Associate.Where(Function(a) a.AssociateId = 123).Select( Function(a) a.AssociateId).ToList()` also fail similarly? i.e. using method syntax, and a different property in the Where - if so, does it then start failing if you introduce the byte property to the where?

Comment: How about `Where a.Inactive.HasValue AndAlso a.Inactive = 0`? Or perhaps `Where Object.Equals(a.Inactive, 0)` from [Compare nullable types in Linq to Sql](https://stackoverflow.com/q/586097/1115360), which has some extra notes on the problem.

Comment: @Andrew So it definitely has to do with nullable types. The query from Caius translated correctly because AssociateId is an int, and not nullable.
Also this did not translate:
`Dim associates = (From a In DatabaseContext.Associate
                          Where (a.Inactive.HasValue AndAlso a.Inactive = 0)
                          Select a.AssociateId).ToList()`

It produced this: `SELECT a.Inactive, a.AssociateID
FROM associate AS a
WHERE a.Inactive IS NOT NULL`. Very odd, I will try next the same EF core version but a different sql data provider.

Comment: Ok so it maybe seems like something to do with VB and C#. My EF is in a Class Library which is C#. We use this library everywhere in all our other projects. One of the other projects is in VB.NET. If I run the same query, with the same EF Core version and database and same provider in C#, it runs just fine and adds the "WHERE" to the SQL. Same code in VB does not. So it has something to do with the Nullable compare in VB, which is somehow caca compared to C#.

Comment: Ok so it is not a nullable problem. If I make the Inactive property as byte instead of byte? it still doesn't work. It has to do with VB using a C# Class Library where the EF Core and Models live. The issue has to be there...

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, seems the answer is to make the query more specific in VB. I guess the query conversion between C# class library and VB project seems to be the issue.

```
Dim associates = (From a In DatabaseContext.Associate
                  Where a.Inactive.Value = Convert.ToByte(0)
                  Select a.AssociateId).ToList()
```

This provides the correct query:

```
SELECT `a`.`AssociateID`
FROM `associate` AS `a`
WHERE `a`.`Inactive` = 0
```

Very weird that in C# you don't have to check against the .Value and convert the 0 to a byte but in VB I had to do it, there was no other way to get it work. Thanks for everyone trying to help with this.